# Как делают такие окна?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Ребята, подскажите, а как пишутся [вот такие](http://www.proimpact7.com/samples/pass4sure/p4semail-popup/page51.html) вылезающие окна? Ну, то есть вы, к примеру, работаете с сайтом, а у вас - бац-  и вот такое окно выскакивает.

ЗЫ. Если не сложно и у кого-то есть под рукой, был бы признателен, если бы Вы не только объяснили, но и показали пример кода такой фишки. Думаю вы со мной согласитесь, что часто по коду всё же становится яснее, чем когда на пальцах объясняют. Ну, и его можно потрогать, покрутить и станет яснее.

Comment: на http://smartresponder.ru/ можно создать такое окно для рассылки

Comment: Ссылки делайте кликабельными.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример [jQuery-UI Dialog](http://www.linkexchanger.su/2009/95.html)

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую "потрогать".

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Очень хорошо получилось.

Comment: Пожалуйста ))